# How do I return a nicer status message / "Stopped reason" from my ECS / Docker container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have a microservice that I would normally have used Lambda for but it occasionally takes longer than 5 mins.  So I created a docker container and set it up so that every time I run it, it does it's business and then stops.  It works great and I'm happy with it.

What I'm not happy with is the the ECS "Last status" for the task shows "STOPPED" in red letters and shows the "Stopped reason" as "Essential container in task exited".  Is there some way to make this show "Success" in green and/or change the stopped reason to "Successful termination" or similar?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you flipped the bit that indicates "essential" in the container definition, perhaps it wouldn't be considered an error. A "service" is a long running thing so maybe what you are really looking for is to just run a task from the aws cli, and not have it live as a service with 0 running tasks. Another option would be in the service something running as an api that on request runs the task via aws sdk.

Comment: I'm not using a service, just a task (the service keeps the task running constantly, which I don't want).  I tried to create a new version of my task with the essential flag set to false but on save it gave me the following error: `Task definition doesn't have any essential container.`  I think you have to have an essential container?

Comment: The other part of my comment is what you are looking for then. Run you task from a task definition directly with the aws command line client, or aws sdk for your favorite language. 

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/run-task.html

The task will spin up, run it's entrypoint script or cmd and exit. No service is needed in this case

Comment: Yeah, I'm not using a service (nor did I ever use a service).  I definitely don't want this to be a service.  I still see the Last Status as STOPPED in red in the console for my task :-(.

Comment: How are you starting your task now if you don't have a service setup?

Comment: I had been testing it manually by running the task through the AWS console.  I was planning on executing the task using a periodic lambda function to kick it off.  I have a new approach now which uses a constantly running service and a cron job running inside a spring container so that it never ends and I avoid this issue.  I guess ECS isn't really meant for periodic tasks like this.